# php : word proximity script? [2nd attempt]

Tags: php, proximity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php : word proximity script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531665/php-word-proximity-script)

Word Proximity Redux.

I would like to make a php script that can scan a chunk of text (any length),
and look for specified/defined terms.

I then want to measure the Distance between those occurances (if any).

Distance as is Physical Distance - the number of Words/Characters that lay between occurences.
(I do Not mean Spelling/Sounding/Character count etc. - just the number of items the separate).

Example:
Specific terms to look for = Word1 Word2
Specific text to scan = Blah blah Word1 blah blah Word2 blah.
Result would be = Word1-Word2:+2 distance

(I seriously hope I've explained this clearly enough and better than my first attempt)

.

I've scouted around, looked at Google/here/other forums etc. - and I'm not seeing anything that matches, that's why I'm posting here.

The above is the most basic of desires, as eventually I'd like to be able to scan and look at whether occurances were within the same contextual chunk (such as paragraph, beneath the same heading or a separate one etc.).
Thus the end goal could be to score it based on the actual distance of words and semantic blocks.